# CircleAvatar Exception: Invalid image data handle in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am using CircleAvatar to show a background image:

```
CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 20,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      backgroundImage: foregroundImage.image,
                    ),
```

but now it always show this error:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:5275:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:5143:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodec (dart:ui/painting.dart:1999:60)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://static.poemhub.top/2021/5/18/laitn.github.io-favicon.ico", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://static.poemhub.top/2021/5/18/laitn.github.io-favicon.ico", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

To fix this problem, I tried this way:

```
final Image defaultImage = Image.asset('images/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@3x.png');
    var foregroundImage = counter.value.favIconUrl == "" ? defaultImage : Image.network(
        global.staticResourceUrl + "/" + counter.value.localIconUrl,
      loadingBuilder: (context,child,loadingProgress)=>(loadingProgress == null) ? child : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => defaultImage,
    );
```

if image fetch failed or other error, set a default image. But still not fix this problem. I figure out maybe the image think this url icon correct, but CircleAvatar render failed. Is it possible to check the image valid before render using CircleAvatar? what should I do to avoid this problem? How to know the image could render successful? I also have tried to set both foreground picture and background picture like this:

```
 CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 20,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      foregroundImage:  foregroundImage.image,
                      backgroundImage: defaultImage.image,
                    ),
```

but it looks like this:

[image]

both have background and foreground picture.

Comment: You can simply just use the `backgroundImage` as a `fallback` if `foregroundImage` fails to load. Are you saying, you are not able to do this ?

Comment: some image if the foreground loading success, the background pic and foregound pic may conflict,if the forground pic is transparent, so I could not do like this. @NisanthReddy the picture is obfussion.

Comment: To avoid the transparant picture, I just only set one layer of picture.

Comment: seems like `.ico` is not supported by flutter.

Comment: it supported. the icon image is supported by flutter because a lot of avatar of my app is icon, actually all of the avatar is icon fetched from rss source website. I think maybe the image is not a valid iamge cause this problem. @NisanthReddy

Comment: might  be possible.

Comment: try converting you image and then using it.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isErrorOccured = false;

CircleAvatar(

            radius: 36,
             child: isErrorOccured?Image.asset(""):Image.network(""),
                onBackgroundImageError: (_, __) {
                  setState(() {
                   isErrorOccured = true;
                  });
                },
       
          ),
```

or

```
SizedBox(

        height: height,
        width: height,
        child: ClipRRect(
          child: networkImageUrl == ''
              ? Image.asset(assetImageUrl, fit: BoxFit.cover)
              : CachedNetworkImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  imageUrl: networkImageUrl,
                  placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(
                    child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
                  ),
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.error,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height / 2),
        ))
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case when loading the NetworkImage fails with 404 the backgroundImage is shown correctly.

```
child: CircleAvatar(
           radius: 30,
           foregroundImage: NetworkImage('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597223557154'),
           backgroundImage: const AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'), 
),
```